How to mirror serial output ttyS0 to the HDMI /dev/dri/card0?
When I starting my single board computer, I can face the output from the UART, or even called /dev/ttyS0. I want to mirror everything to my HDMI port which is placed on /dev/dri/card0.
How can I achieve that? Here I'm running the command drm_info. I'm using Ubuntu 24.04 LTS.
>> drm_info
[?2004l
Node: /dev/dri/card0
├───Driver: stm (STMicroelectronics SoC DRM) version 1.0.0 (20170330)
│   ├───DRM_CLIENT_CAP_STEREO_3D supported
│   ├───DRM_CLIENT_CAP_UNIVERSAL_PLANES supported
│   ├───DRM_CLIENT_CAP_ATOMIC supported
│   ├───DRM_CLIENT_CAP_ASPECT_RATIO supported
│   ├───DRM_CLIENT_CAP_WRITEBACK_CONNECTORS supported
│   ├───DRM_CAP_DUMB_BUFFER = 1
│   ├───DRM_CAP_VBLANK_HIGH_CRTC = 1
│   ├───DRM_CAP_DUMB_PREFERRED_DEPTH = 0
│   ├───DRM_CAP_DUMB_PREFER_SHADOW = 0
│   ├───DRM_CAP_PRIME = 3
│   ├───DRM_CAP_TIMESTAMP_MONOTONIC = 1
│   ├───DRM_CAP_ASYNC_PAGE_FLIP = 0
│   ├───DRM_CAP_CURSOR_WIDTH = 64
│   ├───DRM_CAP_CURSOR_HEIGHT = 64
│   ├───DRM_CAP_ADDFB2_MODIFIERS = 1
│   ├───DRM_CAP_PAGE_FLIP_TARGET = 0
│   ├───DRM_CAP_CRTC_IN_VBLANK_EVENT = 1
│   ├───DRM_CAP_SYNCOBJ = 0
│   └───DRM_CAP_SYNCOBJ_TIMELINE = 0
├───Device: platform st,stm32-ltdc
│   └───Available nodes: primary
├───Framebuffer size
│   ├───Width: [0, 2048]
│   └───Height: [0, 2048]
├───Connectors
│   └───Connector 0
│       ├───Object ID: 32
│       ├───Type: HDMI-A
│       ├───Status: connected
│       ├───Physical size: 1210x680 mm
│       ├───Subpixel: unknown
│       ├───Encoders: {0}
│       ├───Modes
│       │   ├───1920x1080@30.00 driver phsync pvsync 16:9 
│       │   ├───1920x1080@25.00 driver phsync pvsync 16:9 
│       │   ├───1920x1080@24.00 driver phsync pvsync 16:9 
│       │   ├───1280x720@60.00 driver phsync pvsync 
│       │   ├───1280x720@60.00 driver phsync pvsync 16:9 
│       │   ├───1280x720@50.00 driver phsync pvsync 16:9 
│       │   ├───720x576@50.00 driver nhsync nvsync 16:9 
│       │   ├───720x576@50.00 driver nhsync nvsync 4:3 
│       │   ├───720x480@59.94 driver nhsync nvsync 16:9 
│       │   └───720x480@59.94 driver nhsync nvsync 4:3 
│       └───Properties
│           ├───"EDID" (immutable): blob = 44
│           ├───"DPMS": enum {On, Standby, Suspend, Off} = On
│           ├───"link-status": enum {Good, Bad} = Good
│           ├───"non-desktop" (immutable): range [0, 1] = 0
│           ├───"TILE" (immutable): blob = 0
│           ├───"CRTC_ID" (atomic): object CRTC = 0
│           └───"dithering": enum {Off, On} = Off
├───Encoders
│   └───Encoder 0
│       ├───Object ID: 31
│       ├───Type: DPI
│       ├───CRTCS: {0}
│       └───Clones: {0}
├───CRTCs
│   └───CRTC 0
│       ├───Object ID: 38
│       ├───Legacy info
│       │   └───Gamma size: 256
│       └───Properties
│           ├───"ACTIVE" (atomic): range [0, 1] = 0
│           ├───"MODE_ID" (atomic): blob = 0
│           ├───"OUT_FENCE_PTR" (atomic): range [0, UINT64_MAX] = 0
│           ├───"VRR_ENABLED": range [0, 1] = 0
│           ├───"GAMMA_LUT": blob = 0
│           └───"GAMMA_LUT_SIZE" (immutable): range [0, UINT32_MAX] = 256
└───Planes
    ├───Plane 0
    │   ├───Object ID: 34
    │   ├───CRTCs: {0}
    │   ├───Legacy info
    │   │   ├───FB ID: 0
    │   │   └───Formats:
    │   │       ├───ARGB8888 (0x34325241)
    │   │       ├───XRGB8888 (0x34325258)
    │   │       ├───RGB888 (0x34324752)
    │   │       ├───RGB565 (0x36314752)
    │   │       ├───ARGB1555 (0x35315241)
    │   │       ├───XRGB1555 (0x35315258)
    │   │       ├───ARGB4444 (0x32315241)
    │   │       ├───XRGB4444 (0x32315258)
    │   │       └───C8 (0x20203843)
    │   └───Properties
    │       ├───"type" (immutable): enum {Overlay, Primary, Cursor} = Primary
    │       ├───"FB_ID" (atomic): object framebuffer = 0
    │       ├───"IN_FENCE_FD" (atomic): srange [-1, INT32_MAX] = -1
    │       ├───"CRTC_ID" (atomic): object CRTC = 0
    │       ├───"CRTC_X" (atomic): srange [INT32_MIN, INT32_MAX] = 0
    │       ├───"CRTC_Y" (atomic): srange [INT32_MIN, INT32_MAX] = 0
    │       ├───"CRTC_W" (atomic): range [0, INT32_MAX] = 0
    │       ├───"CRTC_H" (atomic): range [0, INT32_MAX] = 0
    │       ├───"SRC_X" (atomic): range [0, UINT32_MAX] = 0
    │       ├───"SRC_Y" (atomic): range [0, UINT32_MAX] = 0
    │       ├───"SRC_W" (atomic): range [0, UINT32_MAX] = 0
    │       ├───"SRC_H" (atomic): range [0, UINT32_MAX] = 0
    │       ├───"IN_FORMATS" (immutable): blob = 35
    │       │   └───DRM_FORMAT_MOD_LINEAR (0x0)
    │       │       ├───ARGB8888 (0x34325241)
    │       │       ├───XRGB8888 (0x34325258)
    │       │       ├───RGB888 (0x34324752)
    │       │       ├───RGB565 (0x36314752)
    │       │       ├───ARGB1555 (0x35315241)
    │       │       ├───XRGB1555 (0x35315258)
    │       │       ├───ARGB4444 (0x32315241)
    │       │       ├───XRGB4444 (0x32315258)
    │       │       └───C8 (0x20203843)
    │       ├───"alpha": range [0, UINT16_MAX] = 65535
    │       └───"zpos" (immutable): range [0, 0] = 0
    └───Plane 1
        ├───Object ID: 39
        ├───CRTCs: {0}
        ├───Legacy info
        │   ├───FB ID: 0
        │   └───Formats:
        │       ├───ARGB8888 (0x34325241)
        │       ├───RGB888 (0x34324752)
        │       ├───RGB565 (0x36314752)
        │       ├───ARGB1555 (0x35315241)
        │       ├───ARGB4444 (0x32315241)
        │       └───C8 (0x20203843)
        └───Properties
            ├───"type" (immutable): enum {Overlay, Primary, Cursor} = Overlay
            ├───"FB_ID" (atomic): object framebuffer = 0
            ├───"IN_FENCE_FD" (atomic): srange [-1, INT32_MAX] = -1
            ├───"CRTC_ID" (atomic): object CRTC = 0
            ├───"CRTC_X" (atomic): srange [INT32_MIN, INT32_MAX] = 0
            ├───"CRTC_Y" (atomic): srange [INT32_MIN, INT32_MAX] = 0
            ├───"CRTC_W" (atomic): range [0, INT32_MAX] = 0
            ├───"CRTC_H" (atomic): range [0, INT32_MAX] = 0
            ├───"SRC_X" (atomic): range [0, UINT32_MAX] = 0
            ├───"SRC_Y" (atomic): range [0, UINT32_MAX] = 0
            ├───"SRC_W" (atomic): range [0, UINT32_MAX] = 0
            ├───"SRC_H" (atomic): range [0, UINT32_MAX] = 0
            ├───"IN_FORMATS" (immutable): blob = 40
            │   └───DRM_FORMAT_MOD_LINEAR (0x0)
            │       ├───ARGB8888 (0x34325241)
            │       ├───RGB888 (0x34324752)
            │       ├───RGB565 (0x36314752)
            │       ├───ARGB1555 (0x35315241)
            │       ├───ARGB4444 (0x32315241)
            │       └───C8 (0x20203843)
            ├───"alpha": range [0, UINT16_MAX] = 65535
            └───"zpos" (immutable): range [1, 1] = 1
[?2004hroot@stm32-os:~# 


What output exactly? The console messages from the host kernel that is sent via UART?

@u1686_grawity yes. When the kernel is booting, then I can see the boot process log through the UART, e.g ttyS0. I want to connect that log to the HDMI.

Specify console=tty0 in the kernel command line to have it go to the framebuffer console (the compiled-in default is likely set to console=ttyS0). This won't use DRI directly; rather it will use the virtual console layer on top of fbcon (on top of DRI, I think).
As far as I know, the kernel only supports one console message output at a time. User-space components, like systemd, might use multiple console= settings so you can keep the ttyS0 one as well, but the kernel only outputs to the last console specified.
I remember Plymouth used to be the recommendation for duplicating messages across multiple consoles, although it of course only starts as an user-space service and can't do anything with the early-boot kernel messages.
